# How to use paypal subscription revise

Tags: paypal

I am just curious if it is possible to use the Paypal subscription Button revise method with a subscription that is of the status "APPROVAL_PENDING".

```
paypal.Buttons({

        createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
  
          return actions.subscription.revise("I-HAHWJUY845PE", {
  
            'plan_id': 'P-6GE98585DE1334530MJ3IPDA',
  
          });
  
        },
  
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
  
          alert('You have successfully created subscription ' + data.subscriptionID); // Optional message given to subscriber

        }
      }).render('#P-8B719909FS0268804MJ3IPDA'); // Replace with your plan ID
```

I have tried but it keeps failing, saying resource is not found!!

Answer (score 0):

No. If approval is pending, create a new subscription rather than revising one that was never approved to begin with, and forget about it.

Comment: Thank you! I am just trying to figure a better to use the buttons alongside the API.